# Make Excel/VBA generate file name based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to copy and paste values from one excel file to another and it works great:

```
Sub TransferValues()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet



Set wb1 = Workbooks("ABC.xls") 
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("SHEET1") 

Set wb2 = Workbooks("CBA") 
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("SHEET2") 


'This line puts the value from wb1.ws1 in wb2.ws2, cells specified:
ws2.Range("O3:O33").Value = ws1.Range("I82:I112").Value
ws2.Range("O35:O65").Value = ws1.Range("J82:J112").Value


End Sub
```

BUT, as of right now I have to manually tell VBA that it has to grab the "`ABC`" file.
Is there a way to let Excel read a cell that contains the Workbook name.
So for example workbook `CBA` says in `A1` `ABC`
I was thinking something like: `Set wb1 = Workbooks("(A1).xls")`
Thank you!

Comment: `Set wb1 = Workbooks(wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value)`

Comment: I get a `Run-time Error '91'`